# How does the price of 1 BTC compare to other commodities?

Tags: trading, exchange-rate, value, marketplace

I'm looking for a chart of Bitcoin's price and market cap to other commodities like silver, gold, etc.

Does such a chart exist?

Why is this useful? Because I want to see how the USD compares to similar non-Fiat, limited quantity resources.  This should show how Bitcoin is undervalued, or would give us insight into the trade volumes.

If it doesn't exist, I'll create it myself for the benefit of the community. Where can I get historic gold & silver pricing in USD?

Comment: Your first question is localized and likely to change, and your second is not really bitcoin related.

Comment: He asked if there is a chart with that comparison, it's not OT!

Comment: hi makerofthings7, I think any such comparison would simply be made through the USD pricing history on sites such as bitcoincharts.com .  As such, the "gold and silver" part of this question starts to make it off-topic here.  If there were bitcoin-denominated exchanges trading these commodities  in significant volumes, then there might be a bitcoin-related answer that could be given, but as far as I know there are not (unlike USD).  Again, it's nothing personal, but this question will likely end up closed just because of how the bitcoin stack exchange is curated.

Answer (score 1):

http://pricedingold.com/charts/BTC-2010.pdf This is a comparision chart for btc vs. miligrams of gold i guess you could reverse it against history of silver or some other commodities. You can get the complete article here http://pricedingold.com/bitcoin/